# Apache httpd load driver oracle

Tags: oracle, apache

I am trying to configure the apache httpd to connect to an oracle database.

But whenever I start httpd, the following error message occurs:

> [root@oracle1 ~]# service httpd start
>
> Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/apache->logging.conf:
> DBD: Can't load driver file apr_dbd_oracle.so
> [FAILED]

Here is my `mod_dbd` configuration:

```
`DBDriver oracle` 
`DBDParams "server=172.17.1.188:1521 dbname=DB11G user=oracle1 >pass=123456a"`
`DBDMin  4`
`DBDKeep 8`
` DBDMax  20`
` DBDExptime 300`
` Listen 9001 `
```

I found an article describes way to solve this issue by building `apr` and `apr-util` package [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread/%3C49142D36.1050706@sbcmaroc.com%3E?%3C%3Eusers.httpd.apache.org%3E).

BUT, I cant make `apr_dbd_oracle.so` file like they did in the article.

So, what do I need to do to solve this problem?